# ACCESS SQL query sum(log()) returns "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was trying to run a query but got "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error. After a few trial I figured out it's because of a null record.

Even though I found the cause, I didn't get the reason. When there is null record, why the following queries behave differently?

```
SELECT sum(log(number)) FROM COM;  //returns error
SELECT log(sum(number)) FROM COM;  //returns number
SELECT log(number) FROM COM;       //returns number
SELECT sum(number) FROM COM;       //returns number
```

Hope others find this post helpful as well.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Was `number` null for every trial?

Comment: yes, all trials are on the same data. But the 3rd trial is not an aggregate function, so it returns a set of numbers.